# Dynamically allocate and modify memory from function in C++

Tags: c++

I want to read a file and allocate an array containing the read values, that I will later use.

Here's what I got:

```
int main(){
float *values;

somefunction (&values);
values[3]=3;  //Works OK but I want to modify it from the other function

}

somefunction(float ** values){

//I read the file here and count the lines
//for the sake of simplicity lets say I got lines=10;

*values = new float[lines]; //Works OK
*values[0]=0;  //Works OK because it points to the first or only element
*values[1]=1;  //Segmentation Fault

}
```

Why is it OK to modify the new allocated array of floats from the main function, and not from the same function where it was allocated, what am I doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure my syntax to modify the array is wrong but I don't know why..., thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is C++, use a vector, rather than messing around with double pointers and manual memory management.

Comment: Try `(*values)[1] = 1`

Comment: Long story but I can't use STL vectors :/

Comment: What does this has to do with `C` if you are using `new`?

Comment: Comment # 2 solved it, and it actually makes sense, thanks sigfpe

Comment: And I can't use STL vectors, and it wouldn't make a difference for me to use malloc() instead of new() that's why it has to do with C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easier to read...

```
somefunction(float*& values)
{
    values = new float[lines];
    values[0] = 0;
    values[1] = 1;
}

main()
{
    float* values;
    somefunction(values);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator. Thus, `*values[1]` is the same as `*(values[1])`. What you want is `(*values)[1]`, as @sigfpe pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler still:

```
float* somefunction()
{
    float* values = new float[lines];
    values[0] = 0;
    values[1] = 1;
    return values;
}

main()
{
    float* values = somefunction();
}
```

Comment: Indeed for this example this is simpler, if re-using existing pointers then a reference can be useful.

Comment: This is simpler, but I'd rather use void somefunction() since I will return more than one reference, thanks.

Comment: @aehs29, in that case, the approach used by Curg's answer is the right one to use.